# Trying to find documentation of the Tor client implementation

Tags: documentation, tor

I am really interested in how the Tor protocol, especially the client interaction, works. I could not find any (easy to understand) documentation of the implementation of the Tor client.

In my research, I could only find superficial articles and libraries like torpy, which seem to be outdated. The original C implementation and new Rust implementation are quite advanced and hard to understand.

Comment: All the official specs are here: https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/